# Replace empty by 0

Tags: excel, vba, substitution

I want to check all cells in columns D to O. If the cell is empty, replace it by a hard zero.

I have this code:

```
Sub replace()
Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
Dim aantalrijen As Long

    With Worksheets("Schaduwblad")
        aantalrijen = .Range("A1", .Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Cells.Count - 1
        Set rng = .Range(.Cells(2, "D"), .Cells(aantalrijen, "O"))

        For Each cell In rng
            cell = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(cell, "", "0")
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

This code hangs during processing. Only option is to end the routine by pressing Escape.

Comment: Can't you use Find and Replace and avoid a loop altogether?

Comment: no, because the data is on a hidden worksheet and it is a returning procedure for every 4 weeks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never used the substitute methode.. I would do this by checking if cell is empty with the `IsEmpty()` function.

So yo can swap

`cell = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(cell, "", "0")`

with

`If IsEmpty(cell) Then cell.value = 0`

Full code:

```
Sub replace()
Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
Dim aantalrijen As Long

  With Application.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Schaduwblad")
        aantalrijen = .Range("A1", .Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Cells.Count - 1
        Set rng = .Range(.Cells(2, "D"), .Cells(aantalrijen, "O"))


    For Each cell In rng
        If IsEmpty(cell) Then cell.value = 0
    Next
  End With
End Sub
```

Comment: your code helped me transferring the empty cells by 0 for the largest data file in just a really short time.

Comment: @DutchArjo Glad I could help, you might be able to run it abit fast if you don't already have `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` in the beginning and then `Application.ScreenUpdating = True` at the end.

Answer (score 6):

You don't need to loop through all the cells. Let Excel find the empties with **.SpecialCells**:

```
On Error Resume Next
rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks, xlCellTypeConstants).Value = 0
On Error GoTo 0
```

The error trap is required in case no empty cells are found.

---

So your whole routine could be replaced with:

```
Sub replace()

    On Error Resume Next

      With Worksheets("Schaduwblad")
            .Range(.Cells(2, "D"), .Cells(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row, "O")) _
                .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks, xlCellTypeConstants).Value = 0
      End With

    On Error GoTo 0

End Sub
```

---

Further to your comment below, here is a version of the same code, but working on a row-by-row basis. To test this, I built a 227,000 x 15 block of data and then using a random number generator punched 100,000 holes into it, emptying those cells. I then ran the following code, which took 33 seconds to fill those 100,000 holes back in.

```
Sub replace()

Dim rangesection As Range

    On Error Resume Next

      With Worksheets("Schaduwblad")
        For Each rangesection In .Range(.Cells(2, "D"), .Cells(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row, "O")).Rows
            rangesection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks, xlCellTypeConstants).Value = 0
        Next
      End With

    On Error GoTo 0

End Sub
```

Comment: for most of my templates, the code works perfectly. However, I am now running into problems with another one where it takes up a lot of time before the routine is finished. I am wondering why. The problem-template has a total of 227850 lines whereas a template which works fine has 87360 lines. so the problem templates has about 3 times more lines to check but I takes much much more time to run (i have been waiting for at least 15 minutes, then I cancelled the execution)

Comment: I just used the above code on a 227,000 x 15 cell table, where most were blank and it took less than 2 seconds to change them all to `0`.

Comment: If the answer you've selected works quicker, please let me know as I'd like to understand how.

Comment: The reason for the delays is down to the building of the range of empty cells. The only way to make this quicker is to understand the nature of the empty cells. Are they likely to exist in solitude, or are they more likely to sit with other blanks in the same row or column. Are they in large contiguous blocks, or are they in singles dotted around. Based on the assumption that they are singles dotted about (worst case scenario) and a table that is approx 10-15 cells wide, I'd suggest running the macro *down* the table one row at a time. I'll add to my answer.

Comment: It did, but think it may have something to do with the formatting of the cells. The cells are empty but I saw there was formatting. It made quite a difference, although I do not know the exact reason.

Comment: It probably goes without saying, but make sure Calcs are off. Calculations based on changes (and conditional formatting based on calcs) will obviously slow things down. Have you tried the row-by-row code?